# Using gulp-uncss on a Wordpress site

Tags: css, wordpress, gulp

Is it possible to use gulp-uncss with Wordpress? If yes then what would be the procedure to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey ok I finally figured this out and it seems pretty easy.
I followed along multiple articles like MandsatWork suggested.

Basically I combined a simple tutorial on using gulp-uncss (on a simple non-Wordpress website) with a grunt Uncss tutorial.

I wrote a whole tutorial on doing this step by step here: http://uplifted.net/programming/remove-unused-css-wordpress-using-gulp/

So the basics:

1) You should have gulp and gulp-uncss in your project directory already (If not go do it!)

2) In your gulp.js file write the gulp task to uncss - It should look something like this:

```
 //Include Gulp
   var gulp = require('gulp');

//Include plugins
  var uncss = require('gulp-uncss');

//Rename is included to rename the uncssed file
  var rename = require('gulp-rename');

//Uncss task
 gulp.task('uncss', function() {
//Where the bloated CSS lives
 gulp.src('lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css')       
   .pipe(uncss({ 
         html: [ 
                'http://wordpress[dot]dev/','http://wordpress-gulp[dot]dev/page-1/' 
                ]
               }))  
   //Add a suffix to avoid confusion      
   .pipe(rename({suffix: '.clean'}))
   //The destination of new uncssed file
   .pipe(gulp.dest('lib/bootstrap/css/'));
```

That's how you do it at it's most basic. If you have many pages I recommend using Grunt Sitemap Generator plugin for Wordpress in https://gist.github.com/lgladdy/10586308

Install it using it's instructions and then go to yourwordpresdomain.com?show_sitemap

Copy the array and paste it's content here:

```
 .pipe(uncss({ 
         html: [ 
 REPLACE THIS URLS ====> 'URL-1/','URL-2/page-1/' 
                ]
               }))
```

Then just run gulp uncss :)

Comment: gulp-uncss breaks my drop down of my bootstrap navigation. Did you encounter any similar problems?

Comment: Hey, so I am new at Node and grunt and I am trying to understand exactly how I can do this. I am using filezilla to move files around. Do I simply add gulp and gulp-uncss  in my child theme?

Comment: @LoveAndHappiness From the Uncss docs... "UnCSS only runs the Javascript that is run on page load. It does not (and cannot) handle Javascript that runs on user interactions like button clicks. You must use the ignore option to preserve classes that are added by Javascript on user interaction."